# How can I get SVN log information by passing URL

Tags: ios, svn, github, tortoisesvn, git-svn

actually I want to show SVN Log information on iOS device, When I particular select project that time I want to show "Comments" and "Change file names".

For this I use such type url string. 
eg:.http://svn.com/subversion/SVNDemo/

I really don't know which string I want to append that URL which gives following information.

1) Revisions
2) Comments for that particular version 
3) date and time stamp 
4) and change file info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the log by calling a URL from a plain HTTP client. You will need a Subversion client, or a repository browser installed on the server such as [ViewVC](http://viewvc.org/) (which you can then see through any web browser).

Comment: Ok, I got your answer and I have a Subversion Client But can you please told me which string i have to append that URL and I get the version information e.g.: http://svn.com/subversion/SVNDemo/?logfile like this.

Comment: There is no string you can add for that. That's what I'm telling you. Not unless you write your own interface for it on the web server.

Comment: What SVN client do you "have"? Check the API/documentation to find out how to use it to get a log.

Comment: Actually last time you write "You will need Subversion Client" so I search that string and I got many results so that I told you, I have SVN Client

Comment: But you still can't get to a log with an unspecified client using just a URL. From the SVN command-line client, you have to call `svn log` (maybe with some other switches) and parse that. Or if you're embedding in an application, you should probably use a Subversion client library and use the appropriate API call that corresponds to `svn log`.

Comment: Do you this link helps me "https://chemistry.apache.org/objective-c/objectivecmis.html". I try to do it but steel not get answer

Comment: That link has nothing to do with Subversion